# Звуки в javaFX.

Tags: java, javafx

Можно ли установить определенное время звучания?

Если можно с примером, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускать **javafx.scene.media.AudioClip** можно как при оббработке любого события так и по таймеру **java.util.Timer**.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Sandbox extends Application {
    Timer myTimer;
    AudioClip alarm = new AudioClip("https://freesound.org/data/previews/423/423322_8471092-lq.mp3");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        myTimer =  new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                alarm.play();
            }
        } , 1000); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, а подскажите как многократно озвучить какое либо событие? Пишу игру и нужно озвучить звук выстрела. 

Данный код работает не вполне корректно.

//условие пересечения лазера и врага 
                    if (bullet.intersects(enemy_ar.get(i))) {
                        
                        detonationsound.play();
                        detonationsound.stop();
}